# Book recommendations for circle geometry, coordinate geometry, and trigonometry for Math Olympiads

Tags: contest-math, book-recommendation

Well, my triangles is covered from EGMO, Evan Chen but I feel that circles isn’t really covered. And I also need a book for coord and trig. Could someone suggest books which cover these three topics to a good level(the whole book needn’t be about them, even a good section is appreciated.) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Olympiad geometry questions are deliberately chosen to minimise the chance of an easy coordinate answer.  You will usually need to bash for a long time.  That said, if you have absolutely no idea then spending 3 hours bashing the algebra might be the only way...

Comment: Yes, they’re  usually made that way but what if, not the problem, but a segment, needs coords. Especially how people started to neglect coords(just a bit) after EGMO released